# GroupJoin with one single window ending on completion of streams

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I have two sources of data which are dumping data from separate thread. I am trying to join both sources by a key. I am able to do it using GroupJoin. I have to use Observable.Never so that window never ends. Everything is working fine in terms of joining the streams. When both sources complete dumping data, they call their repective onComplete on Observers. I am expecting streaming to end as soon as OnComplete is received for both the sources. As I have used Observable.Never stream never ends and Oncomplete event of my aggSource is never called.

is there way to tell Rx that close window when OnComplete received for both the sources instead of infinitely keeping it open?

I am new to Rx and not sure if this is something can be achieved. Below is code snippet. Thanks in Advance!!

```
var l = Source1;
var r = Source2;

var q = r.GroupJoin(l,
                _ => Observable.Never<Unit>(), // windows from each left event going on forever 
                _ => Observable.Never<Unit>(), // windows from each right event going on forever
                (left, obsOfRight) => Tuple.Create(left, obsOfRight)); // create tuple of left event with observable of right events

        var joinSource =   q.SelectMany(e => {
            return e.Item2.Where(
               x =>
               {
                 return x.ID== e.Item1.ID;
               })
               .Select(v=>  (Item1:v.Value, Item2: e.Item1.Value));
        });



var aggSource = joinSource.GroupBy(x => x.Item1).SelectMany(grp =>
            {
                return grp.Scan(0.0, (accumulator, current) => accumulator + current.Item2).Select(z => (Group: grp.Key, Value: z));
            });



aggSource.Subscribe(x => dictResults[x.Group] = x,
              y => { Console.WriteLine("Error Ocurred: " + y.Message); completed = true; },
              () => { completed = true; Console.WriteLine("Subcription comnpleted"); }
              );
// dict results is dictionary which is my projection which is shown to View. Right now my view is just console window.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration selector controls the join window overlap - which we need to cut short when either of the sources complete. First, we'll use `LastOrDefaultAsync` to get a notification when an `OnComplete` is emitted.

```
var either = Observable.CombineLatest(l.LastOrDefaultAsync(), r.LastOrDefaultAsync());
```

Now we can modify the duration selector from the sample:

```
var q = r.GroupJoin(l,
                _ => Observable.Never<Unit>().TakeUntil(either), // windows from each left event until l or r completes
                _ => Observable.Never<Unit>().TakeUntil(either), // windows from each right event until l or r completes
                (left, obsOfRight) => Tuple.Create(left, obsOfRight)); // create tuple of left event with observable of right events
```

This should cause a cascade and *complete* the rest of the observable pipeline.

Comment: As Sources are of different type. I had to pass result selector in combineLatest. Apart from that it worked like a  charm Thanks!!